# GitLab API Namespace plan options

Tags: gitlab

I want to check if a specific namespace has a premium or above plan usint the [GitLab Namespace API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/namespaces.html). However I am not sure what values I should consider as premium or above as the list of possible values are not listed.

From the doc, I can see only "default", "gold", "silver" and I am not sure what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

The naming has changed over time. The possible values also depend on whether you are using self-hosted GitLab or cloud-hosted on gitlab.com

You can find the various plan codes [described in the GitLab source code here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/d22d43b6b80274c5bda0ad55710bc38ef04fffea/ee/app/models/ee/plan.rb#L8-23).

So, today, the possible values are:

```
      FREE = 'free'
      BRONZE = 'bronze'
      SILVER = 'silver'
      PREMIUM = 'premium'
      GOLD = 'gold'
      ULTIMATE = 'ultimate'
      ULTIMATE_TRIAL = 'ultimate_trial'
      PREMIUM_TRIAL = 'premium_trial'
      OPEN_SOURCE = 'opensource'
```

For the most part, silver == premium and gold == ultimate. open source is considered an ultimate level entitlement.