# GitLab Self Hosted: Check plan from API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to check if I have access to premium features (such as [group hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#group-webhooks)) for my GitLab instance (self hosted) **from the API**. What endpoint should I call?

**Notes:**

- I thought of checking [the version](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/version.html) and see if it is ending with `-ee` for Enterprise Edition or `-ce` for community edition but this is not enough since I can still have Enterprise Edition but not be subscribed (thus not having access to premium features).
- In the context of group hooks, I also thought of checking the plan associated with the group in particular using the [Namespace API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/namespaces.html) but I get the value `default` which isn't really helpful (see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175352/gitlab-api-namespace-plan-options))
- I also thought about checking the [license of the instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/license.html) but it needs Administrator privileges and I can't assume the available token as such privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make a call to a premium-only feature that doesn't need admin privileges and check if it doesn't return 403.

For example: [listing epics of a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/epics.html#list-epics-for-a-group).